# Randomly grab multiple files and move them to the folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a library of 1000 questions placed in a folder. I want to create a test bank with each exam taken randomly from the library of questions above. Each topic consists of 10 questions that are taken randomly and copied into 1 exam paper. Does the batch script solve this problem?

This is a script to copy a random file I searched for

```
cd e:\finaly01
set n = 0
for %% f in (*) do (
    set /A n+ = 1
    set "file [!n!] = %%f"
)
for /L %%i in (1.1,% time: ~ -1%) by set "dummy =!random!"
set /A "rand = (n*% random%)/32768 + 1"
copy "! file [%rand%]!" "e:\example"
```

Because I want to create 10 random exam questions, I added:

```
for / l% x in (1, 1, 10) due
cd e:\finaly01
set n = 0
for %%f in (*) do (
    set /A n+ = 1
    set "file [!n!] = %%f"
)
for /L %%i in (1.1,% time: ~ -1%) by set "dummy =! random!"
set /A "rand = (n *% random%) / 32768 + 1"
copy "! file [%rand%]!" "e:\example"
```

But it doesn't seem to work, can someone help to solve it?

Comment: Every single line of your scripts have syntax errors. You need to open a command prompt and enter each of the following, in order to learn how to use each command. `for /?`, `cd /?, `set /?` and `copy /?`.

Comment: Sorry because in the script there are some more gaps in the variable. I corrected it.

Comment: Well, »it doesn't seem to work« is not a quite precise error description, don't you think? Please read this: [mcve]! Also go through the [tour] and consult [ask]!

Comment: Same issue, still more syntax errors to fix. In the first script, lines 2, 3, 5, 7, 8 and 9; in the second script, lines 1, 3, 6, 8, 9 and 10.

Comment: set n=0
for %%f in (E:\finaly01\*) do (
 set /A n+=1   
 set "file[!n!]=%%f" 
 ) 
 for /L %%j in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
 set /A "ran=(n*%random%)/32768+1"

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd E:\finaly01
set n=0
for %%f in (*) do (
    set /A n+=1   
    set "file[!n!]=%%f" 
    ) 
    for /L %%j in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
    set /A "ran=(n*%random%)/32768+1""
    copy "!file[%ran%]!" "e:\example"
```

Sorry because in the script there are some more gaps in the variable. I corrected it. This is the code that can run for me! It takes 1 random file after 1 run. Really apologizing for carelessness that lost your time.